# Firefox and Chrome window width/height showing differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My laptop display resolution is 1280 x 800. When I query $(window).width() I get 1420 on Firefox while I get 1280 on Chrome. Why is Firefox showing me a window width greater than my screen resolution?

Comment: Why are you using a library only to show the window dimensions? use:
`screen.height` and `screen.width` for total dimensions, & `screen.availHeight` and `screen.availWidth` for available dimensions. don't forget to check if the screen is zoomed.

Comment: You are querying the width of your browser window, not your physical screen size.  The window width will change if you resize your browser, have more toolbars installed, etc.  @Erik Riberio's suggestion below is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ChrisBarr - I think he is asking why the returned window width is greater than the screen width. And I don't think you can resize the window bigger than the screen.

Comment: Ah, it totally missed that point! Sorry.

Comment: @Derek Yes, you can. just use the firefox Responsive Design View [Ctrl + Shift + M] and set the screen the size you want.

Comment: I have tried the above dimensions with my screen maximised and in Firefox theyre showing 1429 and 893. In Chrome theyre showing as 1280 and 800 (which match my resolution). I guess as far as the aspect is concerned it will not make a difference. However, I was just curious to know why this difference with Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your Firefox window is probably zoomed out.

Reset the zoom using one of the following:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> in some keyboard layouts)
- View (or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) > Zoom > Reset

Comment: That has sorted out the issue. I was unaware that I had my screen zoomed. Thank you all for your responses. My thanks also to Erick Ribeiro.

Comment: @Nabil Kadimi, is there a way to get the screen.width + height independent of the current zoom in FF?

Comment: It sorted me, I had been banging my head against a wall.